# How do I stop JSP page from executing the servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I am just trying to make a simple web app. It should take all inputs, validate them and store it in the database or display error. I'm having problem while validating my form through external javascript. If a field is empty, all the checking is done but the JSP directs the control to the Servlet. I need to stop the JSP page from further going forward. Please help! Here is the code:

JSP:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validationJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Teacher Management System</h1>

<form name="TeacherRegistrationForm" action="TeacherController" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="AddTeacher">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
ID:<input type="text" name="teacherId" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
Name:<input type="text" name="teacherName" />
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
Address:<textarea type="text" rows="5" name="teacherAddress" ></textarea>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
Qualification:<input type="text" name="teacherQualification" />
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
Years Of Experience:<input type="text" name="teacherExp" />
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
Age:<input type="text" name="teacherAge" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="teacherAdd" value="ADD" onclick="validate()"/>
<input type="reset" name="teacherReset" value="RESET FIELDS" /><br><br>
<a href="WelcomePage.jsp" style="text-decoration: underline">Go Back</a>
</td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
    function validate()
{   
    boolean result=false;
    if(document.TeacherRegistrationForm.teacherId.value=="")
    {

        document.TeacherRegistrationForm.teacherId.value= "Please Enter a valid ID";
        document.TeacherRegistrationForm.teacherId.focus();
        alert("Please enter valid ID");
        result=false;

    }else{result=true;}
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**You need to use `<input type="button"`**

You need to change `<input type="submit" name="teacherAdd" value="ADD" onclick="validate()"/>` to as shown below:

```
<input type="button" name="teacherAdd" value="ADD" onclick="validate()"/>
```

`<input type="submit"` submits the form to the servlet, rather use the `<input type="button"` and call the `validate()` (you are doing this) to validate the inputs and once inputs are valid, you can use `document.myform.submit()` to submit the `form`.

You can refer the below updated java script `validate()` method:

```
function validate() {   
   if(document.TeacherRegistrationForm.teacherId.value=="") {
      document.TeacherRegistrationForm.teacherId.value= "Please Enter a valid ID";
      document.TeacherRegistrationForm.teacherId.focus();
      alert("Please enter valid ID");
      return;
    } else{
      document.TeacherRegistrationForm.submit();
    }
}
```